# specifiy UNIQUE key to insert then to update the records

Tags: php

I am trying to update my records with this code below but a new record is being inserted  in my table every time. How can I specify the UNIQUE key to reach my aim?

This is the whole code I have in my php script plus the connection.php file, which just contains the connection statement. In my mysql I just have one database where the route_4 table is being created. My databe just consists of the route_4 table.

PHP script:

```
<?php

$json = '{"latitude":83.16898451,"longitude":31.16561387,"route":4}';

$data = json_decode ( $json );

$route = "route_" . $data->{'route'};
$latitude = $data->{'latitude'};
$longitude = $data->{'longitude'};

require 'connection.php';

// check whether route's table exist.
$results = $con->query ( "SHOW TABLES LIKE'" . $route . "'" ) or die ( mysqli_error () );

if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {
  //"UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2"
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$route."(id, latitude, longitude, created_at)
          VALUES( id, ? , ? , NOW() )
          ON DUPLICATE KEY 
          UPDATE latitude = VALUES(latitude)
               , longitude = VALUES(longitude)";
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$latitude,$longitude);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();

  echo "Table exist";
} else {
  $create =  "CREATE TABLE " . $route . "
       (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
     latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL, 
     longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
     created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)" ;
   $stmt = $con->prepare($create) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();


  echo "table was created";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make below changes in you table structure

1) Remove the existing `Unique` key for column `id`

2) Add `unique` for `latitude` and ''longitude``

`` ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`route_4` ADD UNIQUE (
`latitude` ,
`longitude`
) ``

Once you make both latitude and longitude as group of unique key then your sql query will update record on duplicate entry else will insert.

Hope this helps

Comment: with your changes I not getting the last records deleted just a new one is being inserted if there is some  changes in the records. Is it possible to delete the last records before updating it?